# How can i handle "turn it down" from my Google Assistant skill?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am trying to make a music player app that plays music one after the other. Here is a sample conversation:

```
User: play Beyblade sound
Appl: Playing "Beyblade Burst: The LOUDEST Beyblade?" by "Kevo"
User: turn it down
Appl: <default fallback>
```

What can i do here? Is there a way i can ask google to handle that request without closing my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a known bug currently that volume controls aren't available inside a Conversational Action (either when playing a Media response or audio through SSML).

Comment: I hope Google implements something like `conv.fallback()` so an app can request Assistant to handle the action relating to the request. Do you know of any technical reason this is not available?

Comment: Because by the time it gets to the server it is too late for the device to handle it. So there shouldn't be a "fallback" - you want the device to intercept some commands like "quit" does and only optionally pass some of them along to the Action, which runs on a server.

Comment: Even if it gets to the server, why is it late for the device to handle it? I was thinking that since the app is not able to handle the request, it simply asks Google assistant device to handle the request. Whichever way Actions team goes ahead, i am ok with it. Thanks.

Comment: Because your Action could then block it. (And if it couldn't - why are you getting involved at all? It makes sense with "quit", which isn't blockable, but does give you a chance to reply, but not for other controls.)

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Other than volume, i had another example in mind. Say i have a restaurant order app: app asks "would you like caramelized onion hummus or cilantro jalapeno hummus?" user asks "what is jalapeno?". Now since google assistant can easily find out "what is jalapeno?" app might want google assistant to handle the request instead to trying to find an answer himself. a similar necessity could arise for translate when app gives an italian dish name, and the user asks to translate it (while the app is still active, since you dont want to quit your order is between).